# Getting model in Rails through ajax from another controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Solved this:

I have a following situation:

I have Graph and Node model.

While on graph/show.html.erb I make an ajax post with an id of a Node:

```
   var val = document.getElementById('nodeName').value;
  if(val){
  $.post("/nodes/this_node/", {id:val});    
  console.log(val);
   }
```

How do I get that Node to render on the same page in, for example,  ?

EDIT::
I have a custom POST action in node_controller :

```
def this_node
   @node = Node.find(idd)
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js   
  end
end
```

I had to add app/views/nodes/this_node.js.erb with:

```
  $("#node_div").html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "node_content", :locals => { :node => @node}) %>');
```

and a partial in views/nodes/_node_content.html.erb

```
  <%= @node.content %>
```

All works.

EDIT:
Actually fixed it (above code works)